# "Heavy rains has" "Today's news are"

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

I just found these questions in a test on the internet:

> 1. 'Heavy rains has caused flooding in several parts of the south west.'

Is this sentence right or wrong? Also:

2) 'Today's news are all about the approaching hurricane.'

Is this sentence right or wrong?

The answer key say that both are wrong. Maybe for (1), the lowercase letters for "south west" are the error, I'm not sure. I don't understand what could be wrong with (2).

Comment: Verb agreement: 'rain has' or 'rains have'; 'news is'. The second one is tricky because it looks like a plural but is uncountable: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/news

Comment: @JamesRandom The first is tricky too, because *rain* is normally uncountable, but is countable here.

Comment: @Araucaria I have heard "rains" often enough that it isn't remarkable to me. (I hope that is because I have lived in some very wet countries, rather than the song Africa by Toto: 'I bless the rains down in Africa'.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The questions here want to test your knowledge of English plural, singular and uncountable nouns. They are testing this by seeing whether you make the verb agree with the subject noun phrase.

The noun *rain* is usually uncountable and would take a singular verb. However in weather forecasts, when we are talking about it raining at different times in different places, we sometimes talk about *heavy rain**s***, which is plural. So in example (1), we need:

> Heavy rains **have** caused flooding in several parts of the south west.

In the second example, the word *news* looks like a plural form because it ends in S (it has plural morphology). In addition, in many languages the word for 'news' *is* plural—for example the word *noticias* in Spanish. But in English, the word *news* is uncountable, even though it looks plural. We need singular verb agreement.  So example (2) should read:

> Today's news **is** all about the approaching hurricane.

Some other nouns that look plural but are usually uncountable/singular in English are:

- Some subjects: *mathematics* (and  in British English *maths*), *physics, electronics, politics, ethics* etc
- Some sports and games: *billiards*, *darts*, *tiddlywinks* etc
- Some place names: *Brussels*, *Wales*, *Athens*, *the Netherlands* etc
- Some illnesses, diseases and medical conditions: *rabies, rickets, mumps, measles, the bends* etc

---

**Grammar Note:**

In English we also have some countable nouns whose singular and plural forms both end in S. They take singular or plural verb agreement, depending on the meaning:

- a kennels, two kennels
- a species, two species

Other common words like this include: *means* and *crossroads*.